# Django model foreign key field is not available in migrations during tests

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-testing

I have this model.

```py
class TransportOrder(SomeMixin, models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        to="orders.Order",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="transport_orders",
        help_text=_("Order which was used for creating"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    # Other fields have been removed for simplicity
```

I have forward function in a migration.

```py
def forward(apps, schema_editor):
    TransportOrder = apps.get_model("transportorders", "TransportOrder")
    
    # There is no `order` field printed result.
    print(dir(TransportOrder))

    # I need to filter something by using `TransportOrder.order` foreign key field here. But I receive the error obviously.
```

Since there is no `order` field in `TransportOrder` model provided by `apps.get_model` function, I got the following error.

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'order' into field.`

However, this only happens while running my tests. Otherwise there is no problem. What can cause this issue?

Comment: Have you run ```manage.py migrate``` ?

Comment: Yes, I did run it.

Comment: "this only happens while running my tests", How do you run your tests? If the problem is with your tests you should also have added that code to the question.

Comment: Have you tried to import TransportOrder from a django shell and check if there is a order field available?

Comment: @blondelg Yes I tried that and yes it exists.

Comment: Please provide test traceback and test code that causes error

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat @blondelg Well, not a specific test causing this. It fails on all tests.   `py.test`'s django db setup part. The same error occures also with an empty database.

Comment: Not sure but, are you running tests through ```manage.py test``` ?

Comment: I use `py.test -n auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently somehow, `dependencies=[]` created by `makemigration` was not correct in some of the old migrations.

Manually adding some dependencies in some migrations fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tries the django test tool, it is designed to work well with the project, expecially with database and models.

Each time you run tests, Django builds it own test database you can populate from your tests with objects from your project.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/

Comment: Well, thanks for the suggestion. Will definitely look at it but changing our current tools is not possible. Since it's used widely in all of our projects.